# R Shiny reactive to filter if row contains string

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am using R Shiny to output a table, but I am having trouble filtering in the `reactive` part for the `renderDataTable`. I am using the `mtcars` table in this example, and I am trying to filter by `type`:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("MTCARS"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                     textInput("type",
                               label = "Type", 
                               placeholder = "Type"),)
        ,
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("data")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    selected <- reactive({
        if (length(input$type) != 0) {
            mtcars$type %in% input$type
        } else {
            TRUE
        }
    })
    output$data <- renderDataTable(mtcars[selected(),])
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Currently, `mtcars$type %in% input$type` filters the table based on what the user inputs as the `type`. However, I want to modify this so that:

1. The text does not have to match exactly. Rows that contain `Honda Civic` will show up if the user types `Hond`.
2. The table needs to start out with the full table. Currently it has no row when it is starting despite having the if/else statement.

Comment: For the first point you can have a look at the `grep` and `grepl` functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mtcars` does not have any column type so I had to create one. I used `stringr::str_detect` to include also partially matched types.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "type")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("MTCARS"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id="sidebar",
                 textInput("type",
                           label = "Type", 
                           placeholder = "Type"),)
    ,
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected <- reactive({
    if (length(input$type) != 0) {
      stringr::str_detect(data$type, input$type)
    } else {
      TRUE
    }
  })
  output$data <- renderDataTable(data[selected(),])
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```